# plsql customer information

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

hello im writing a pl/sql that prompts the user to enter the cid and orderid
based on the entered values the procedure should give:
retrieve the date
retrieve the customer
retrieve the vehicle
retrieve the part ordered

the error is:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: What you have tried yet? Show some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error is from assigning a string too long to a varchar, if you show us some code maybe we can help you better